# How can i know what documents have been rejected in Kofax Quality control screen?

Tags: fax, kofax

I have a Kofax batch with multiple documents. The process I want to built is as follows.

1. Check for quality of faxed documents in Kofax QC screen.
2. Reject documents which are not clear, skewed etc..
3. Send a feedback to the submitter.

Question is, where can I find the details of the documents which I have flagged as rejected. Does Kofax keep the tiff images of rejected documents?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to send e.g. an email to update the submitted?

Rejected documents/pages remain in the batch, but are marked as rejected.

I suggest you check the CaptureSV\sources folder for the example custom panel which will allow you to access all the batch info from vb.net (You can also write it in c#, but no c# example code is provided). Check also the developers guide for helpful instructions.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to do. I checked the CaptureSV\source. I found the Images. I can now attach rejected images and send a notification to anyone.